# Puppeteer freezes while loading a page with auto-play audio utility

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have been trying to build a logic to scrape out hash-tags on a website called Mixcloud. But
when I try to execute this function it sometimes freezes without giving any error of any sort. I have also implemented the logic of stoping the auto-play utility of the website using a click function but it gives off a very indeterministic behavior i.e. it sometimes works and sometimes it doesn't. But whenever it does freeze-up, the rest of the code doesn't execute. Eg. The code is executed on each URLs of shows present here https://www.mixcloud.com/ElClubDelViniloArgentina/

main function

```js
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false,
            args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
        });

        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36');

        page.on('dialog', async dialog => {
            await dialog.dismiss();
        });

    await page.goto(url);

    await page.waitForSelector('.PlayButton__PlayButtonContainer-rvh8d9-0 > .PlayButton__PlayerControl-rvh8d9-1 > .PlayButton__PlayButtonIcon-rvh8d9-2 > svg > path')
    if(!await page.evaluate( isButtonPlay ) ) {
        await page.click('.PlayButton__PlayButtonContainer-rvh8d9-0 > .PlayButton__PlayerControl-rvh8d9-1 > .PlayButton__PlayButtonIcon-rvh8d9-2 > svg > path')
    }

    await page.waitForSelector('.show-tags');

    return await page.evaluate( artistWeeklyEvent );
```

artistWeeklyEvent function

```js
    let config = {
        'genreContainerClass': '.show-tags',
        'anchorTag': 'a'
    };
    
    let genres = [];
    let genreContainer = document.querySelector(config.genreContainerClass);
    let tags = genreContainer.getElementsByTagName(config.anchorTag);

    for(let tag of tags) {
        let tmp = tag.childNodes[0].innerHTML.split('>');
        genres.push(tmp[tmp.length-1]);
    }

    return genres;
```

Comment: Maybe try with `--autoplay-policy=user-gesture-required # Don't render video` 

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-launcher/blob/master/docs/chrome-flags-for-tools.md